# Splash screen animation requirements - Icon Dimensions

Tags: android

I am using Splash screen compat library.

I am using an AVD XML (pic 1 below). When I run on android 12 (on emulator via launchbar), I see some animation happening , but my icon is clipped (as in pic 2).

[image: original icon].
[image: Clipped Icon]

Referring Dimensions in documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen#splash-screen-animate-reqs) , it says

1. The icon area must be 432 dp
2. The inner two-thirds of the image is
   visible on the launcher icon, and must be 288 dp

Point a, I was able to correct in the xml by specifying

```
android:width="432dp"
android:height="432dp"
```

But Point b, I am unable to understand. What exactly needs to be 288 dp.

I also looked at the xml given in [example starter kit](https://developer.android.com/static/resources/splash-screen-news-avd-assets.zip)  .

```
      <vector
        android:width="432dp"
        android:height="432dp"
        android:viewportWidth="432"
        android:viewportHeight="432">
```

I don't see a 288 value anywhere.
What am I missing ?

My AVD xml looks like follows :

```
        <vector
        android:name="vector"
        android:width="432dp"
        android:height="432dp"
        android:viewportWidth="192"
        android:viewportHeight="192">
        <path....
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake.
Viewport dimensions need to be 288 (as mentioned in documentation of [splash screen icon](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen#splash_screen_dimensions)) . This displays perfectly in both android 11 and 12.

```
  android:name="vector"
        android:width="432dp"
        android:height="432dp"
        android:viewportWidth="288"
        android:viewportHeight="288">
```